# DataGridLength parameterless constructor isn't documented

Tags: silverlight

As I can see, the DataGridLength parameterless constructor isn't documented in the msdn( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridlength.datagridlength%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
 Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because its a structure.  Structures cannot have an explicit default constructor.  There is always an implied public default constructor for a structure.